# Dynamic script loading works first time but not thereafter

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-loading

I have contact page on my website where I have various social network links (plus an e-mail form) with links at the side to select each one. Clicking a link makes an ajax request to the server, and on success replaces the html of a common div with the response.

Each one has a javascript file associated with it, and this is added as a script tag in the document head on ajax success.

These scripts should evaluate on each load and prepare the DOM in the response. However, I am finding that the first click works perfectly, the script is loaded and executes, but when I go to click on another link, it loads the new script but it never seems to execute. And none of those dynamically loaded scripts work thereafter.

The ajax call for loading each option is bound to each link's click event here:

```
$('.socialLink').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).prop('id').toLowerCase();
  var callingObj = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "./socialMedia/" + id + ".php",
    success: function(msg) {
      $('.socialLink').css('opacity', '0.4');
      $('.socialLink').data('active', false);
      callingObj.css('opacity', '0.9');
      callingObj.data('active', true);
      if ($('#Feed').css('display') !== 'none') {
        $('#Feed').slideToggle(400, function() {
          $('#Feed').html(msg);
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $('#Feed').html(msg);
      }
      $('#Feed').slideToggle(400);
      $.getScript('./script/' + id + '.js');
    }
  });
});
```

The thing is, I dynamically load scripts for each page on the site, too... and don't seem to have any problems with that.

You can see the page I am talking about if you go here http://www.luketimoth.me/contact.me. Only two options actually load any javascript at the moment, the e-mail and twitter ones... the rest are empty js files with only a single comment inside.

EDIT: I am now using jQuery getScript()... I have changed the code above to reflect this. The scripts I am trying to load, which are not working as exepcted, are:

twitter.js (just the standard code twitter gives you for one of their widgets):

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.
js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

email.js:

```
$('#Send').click(function() {
  var senderName = $('#YourName').val();
  var senderEmail = $('#Email').val();
  var emailSubject = $('#Subject').val();
  var emailBody = $('#EmailBody').val();
  $.ajax({
    url:'./script/sendMail.php',
    data: {
      name: senderName,
      email: senderEmail,
      subject: emailSubject,
      body: emailBody
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#success').html(msg);
    }
  });
});

$('input, textarea').focus(function() {
  if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
    this.value = '';
  }
});

$('input, textarea').focusout(function() {
  if (!this.value.length) {
    this.value = this.defaultValue;
  }
});
```

Comment: You're using jQuery...why don't you use `$.getScript()`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ . I'm not sure if it would fix anything, but you might as well use the library

Comment: Just at a glance, you are "adding" duplicate elements with the same ID - seems you should be replacing the element content not adding a new, potentially duplicate one.

Comment: @Ian Using $.getScript() does improve things, I can click to twitter, get the script, then click to e-mail and get that too, but if I click away and click back, the same thing happens... Script doesn't run, DOM elements are not "active" (for want of a better word). EDIT: perhaps I spoke too soon. There seems to be no difference.

Comment: Could we have a glance at the scripts you are importing? it seems to be that problem as everything here seems fine to me... And by the way, since you take the HTML from the Ajax and put it down the DOM, why isn't it the ajaxed html that includes the script tag?

Comment: Is the script you are referring to is executed? I can't find where.'

Comment: there is something wrong with app 20mb of space is being taken for no reason.

Comment: is it necessary to load same js file over and over.

Comment: same with style sheet.

Comment: I agree, it'd be much better to use getScript() instead of rewriting the script node again and again.

Comment: I have updated my question. @Salketer I have included the scripts I am trying to load but are not working as expected.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer it is not necessary to load the same script file over and over... it is necessary to have it executed, though. At least it is for the way in which I want to app to work. I suppose I could preload each portion, plus their respective scripts, then just reveal them when their respective link is clicked, rather than do an ajax call everytime I want to load one. That may be my only solution, but it seems a bit messier and leaves clutter in the DOM background that the user neither sees nor interacts with.

I don't know what you mean about the css file... that is loaded only once AFAIK.

Comment: if you look at dom style tage is added at clicking any tab even if its the one you are at.

Comment: Load: the main page then load everything else in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and suggestions. I decided in the end to load everything in the background rather than make an ajax request every single time.

It's actually a much more responsive page now... admittedly at the cost of having unused DOM elements in the background. Given how much faster it is, though, I think the trade-off is acceptable.